# Set the amount of coupon code 50% of the total cart amout

Tags: magento, coupon

I have created Shopping Cart Price Rule in Magneto admin and also created a coupon code now i want set the discount amount to 50% for the coupon code of the total amount in the cart.

Please help me on this issue.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I got it. was so simple just go to the admin then Promotions > Shopping Cart Price Rule > Actions > Select Percentage of product price from drop down > enter the percentage amount

DONE... !